# google oauth2client in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, oauth2client

I'm writing a program that uses oauth2 library of google for some app in google-app-engine. When I run the server on my machine, it raises an IOError exception of this sort --

```
File "/home/deploy/Downloads/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 592, in __init__
raise IOError(errno.EACCES, 'file not accessible', filename)
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client-1.0c2-py2.7.egg'
```

I have that egg file in the directory it named. I installed it from the google-api-python project page. What am I doing wrong? I also noticed that most of the egg files in the directory also have a ....egg-info file. oauth2client-1.0c2-py2.7.egg-info file in not present. Does that cause the error?

If i open my python interpreter and try to open the file, it succeeds in opening it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must copy the `oauth2client` directory into the `root` directory of your project folder. App Engine requires all used packages to be included.